# ipset -j SET --add-set notwroking in cetos

Tags: linux, centos, iptables

I recently installed ipset rpm and kmod-ipset rpm for my Centos (Linux 2.6.18-194.11.3.el5 i686) and try to hands with help of some examples from internet,
but when I try to ban user who tries to connect to port 443 to remote server add automatically to ipset bann list i get following error.

command= ipset -N banned_hosts iphash

iptables -I FORWARD -p tcp --dport 443 -j SET --add-set banned_hosts src

Error= iptables v1.3.5: Unknown arg `--add-set'

Please help what i am doing wrong.

Comment: iptables is currently at version 1.6.0, upgrade needed badly!

Comment: I assume you have an equally horrible kernel version, 2.6.18, yes you do.

Comment: Why are you still using this ancient version of Centos?  If the hacker realizes your using 2.6.18 he can just exploit the kernel bash vulnerability (fixed 6+ months ago) and gain control of your system.

Comment: is it necessary to upgrade my full Centos? or just use new kernel and update iptables with new rpm ?

Answer (score 0):

The command is valid, but your versions are so old they don't match.  It is possible the kernel and iptables have incompatible protocol versions.  You would have to at minimum download the source code and compile the new version of iptables.  You need to use the make modules and modules_install command to install the new version into the running kernel.  You may have to do the same for ipset.  Available from netfilter.org.

Comment: I do not want to upgrade my full Centos with fresh installation as I am using this machine as a Gateway with 5 Interfaces 1 LAN, 4 ISPs to share Internet for my users since LAST 4 Years. so if I use only new version of Kernel and upgrade iptables rpm, is this fulfil my requirements to use iptables with ipset?

Comment: Yes, if you upgrade the kernel,iptables,and ipset everything should be good.  You need to add **make modules && make modules_install** to the usually set of make commands.